# Battlefield 3 PC boxed, DRM constraints and Origin?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3, drm, origin

Is the boxed version of *Battlefield 3* free from other clients, "services", and DRM?  For instance, the intrusive "always online" DRM, "3-install" limits, Origin, and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. Origin is required for any PC copy (boxed and digital) of Battlefield 3.

Comment: Hallowed are the Ori

Answer (score 7):

Origin is required to play at all times (you can use the offline mode though).

You must also pass a one time release date check the first time you use Battlefield 3, which *requires* the internet. After that you're free to play offline (but still through Origin).